# Bypassing the NAT and open ports through C++ to achieve low latency

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, udp

My purpose is to:

- not ask to the user for opening ports on his router
- doing everything by code with my application

it's possible to do that? Considering that this application is supposed to work only with other machiines with the same application installed can i write some kind of protocol from the ground-up that can do that?

My general idea is to make the connection as fast as possible, i also have to exchange small packets, lowering the delay is much more important for me than just having an high throughput.

Comment: You could use a commonly-open port like port 80, although you will get contention from internet traffic if you do.

Comment: @JamWaffles can give me an examples? Basically i have to filter the packets and/or sign them? I have a general idea of how the TCP/IP stack works but now i'm starting programming this things and i have to go deeper.

Comment: You can use the HTTP protocol as your transport, and you can send and recieve encrypted/signed data over it. If you use HTTPS using an SSL library, you might find it easier to do. Then, the port would be 443, not 80. 443 is also commonly open. And, there is SSH over port 22.

Comment: Or there's hole-punching for P2P: http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

Comment: @Linuxios the "hole punching" technique is not granted to work, i see a question here on Stackoverflow where the user explains why it's not a reliable technique.

Comment: @user827992: It's not reliable, but if you have a protocol that can't be routed through HTTP, HTTPS, or SSH, it's the only option. That said, you should be able to trafic almost anything through HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH.

Comment: @user315052 HTTP is a protocol, i'd like to stick with the TCP/IP and create my own protocol to avoid creating a mess and to simplify the administration of my app, anyway i appreciate your interest and i was considering this as an option but, as i said, it will make everything a little bit too messy.

Comment: If you must create your own protocol, then that is a symptom of NIH syndrome, get yourself checked out by a doctor immediately. :-) More seriously, many applications have been written over HTTP, so you would be in good company if you followed suit. It is just a transport, where writes have a "POST" header, and reads have a "GET" header.

Comment: @user315052 can you provide a complete example in C++ for what you are suggesting?

Comment: If the router is UPNP enabled you can do that. Else you must configure the router by hand. There is no way around this.

Comment: @RedX Upnp is out of the question, i don't know how to code this in the best way but i know that the Upnp can be a serious threat for the security and an experienced user can denied this request; also Upnp is not really well supported by many routers and modems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not mess with the NAT. That won't help with latency all that much anyway. You're using TCP/IP, which is a pretty high level protocol, and is relatively slow. That is - the protocol does a lot of great work for you - but at a cost in terms of latency. ( It maintains connection state, and keeps packets in order, and does a decent job of guaranteeing packet delivery etc. )

If you want a very low latency network channel use UDP - this is lower level, and does not do nearly as much work as TCP. UDP simply does its best to deliver each packet to the destination without maintaining connection open, packets don't necessarily arrive in order, and there is know way to know if the packet even got to its destination.

You need to build those things yourself - or learn to live without them.

Applications built on UDP tend to repeat a lot of information, and implement the protocol logic with a lot of room for error. The result is generally lower latency - but at a cost generally of either reliability or transfer rate.

Also - if you need low latency do NOT tunnel through another protocol like tunneling through SSH or something. This will just increase latency.

Comment: No. But this looks like an example of someone using UPD to achieve low latency high performance data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is geared toward your requirement that you not ask the customer to adjust any settings on their network. If you are okay with having the customer change things on their network for you, then you should just implement your own custom application as Rafael suggests.

You could use the HTTP protocol over port 80 or HTTPS (which is HTTP over SSL/TLS) protocol over port 443 if you need it encrypted. Or use SSH over port 22.

These are just ports that are typically opened up by a firewall, so you are likely to get through. There is no guarantee that they will be open.

The reason to use the HTTP protocol when using the HTTP or HTTPS is that the firewall may be doing deep packet inspection, and it may blackhole or reset your connection if it doesn't match its expectations. Same goes for using SSH over port 22. You might be better off using SSL over 443, and just hope the firewall is not decrypting the data to do HTTP inspection (just remember that it might be decrypting).

For implementation, you could use [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html), or [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: @user827992: I have heard of it. It is a transport that efficiently uses available bandwidth. But, you will have some issues getting UDP traffic through a firewall.